# Is there a tool that can retrieve subject area listings for a journal using an API

Tags: research-process, journals

I'm attempting to characterise a corpus of journal articles by their subject area and categories. I can do this for individual journals using e.g. The SCImago Journal & Country Rank (https://www.scimagojr.com), but I'd like to retrieve the data in bulk. Does anyone know whether this data exists, or whether it's available via an API?

Answer (score 1):

Not an API, but still machine-readable: *Scopus* provides an Excel file comprising the database's coverage, including each journal's disciplines and subject areas. See [this page](https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus/how-scopus-works/content) and click on "Download the Source title list".

([Elsevier provides an API](https://dev.elsevier.com/), too, so it is possible that you might obtain the same information through that venue.)